# Google's usual behavior on examining articles

Tags: google, search-engines, copyright

There is an original content(article) from  a website, I copied it and paste it in a Paraphrasing tool. The tool did a great job in paraphrasing.

I tried checking using copyscape and it did detect paraphrased article. My next question is, how about google would I be penalized or not crawled for this. I understand the ethical issues on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even Though both the articles looks different ( original and duplicate ) Google can easily  separate those articles. Google won't rank your page unless it is original and user lovable. Matt Cutts stated that "[Duplicate Content Won’t Hurt You, Unless It Is Spammy](http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-duplicate-content-wont-hurt-you-unless-it-is-spammy-167459)" If those contents are spammy then Google will penalize you. Majority of the spinning tools are doing bad. They just change the meaning of the words present in the content. It might change the meaning of the content so user won't like those page and close your website suddenly which will increase the **[Bounce rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_rate)** of your website. Google consider both bounce rate and quality of content. See [this](http://searchengineland.com/bounce-rate-as-a-ranking-factor-15643) news

But my question is why don't you write a original content?

Google love those original content. If you have fresh content in your website and if users spent more time in your page, it will increase the credibility of your website and so Google crawl your website quickly.

Comment: TO conclude, Paraphrasing tool is just okay, but I should not spam, make sure that my
article can attract readers, the bounce rate should be low. right?

Comment: Yeah! you are right. You should not spam and your article should attract your readers and the bounce rate should be low.